# Extjs 4 : use cloneConfig() to clone a chart

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

I have a grid with a chart :

[image]

When I click on this chart,a new panel corresponding to the details of this chart is created just below.
howeever, its length is limited to 500px as it is a toolTip.

[image]

My goal is to create a panel to show the detail of this graph covering the entire length of the grid

I used cloneConfig() to create this panel.I tried to set its length to 900px but its not working.

initialiseAll :

var gTimeLinePanelDetail = Ext.getCmp('GlobalTimeLinePanelDetail');

```
if(gTimeLinePanelDetail == undefined)
{
    me.detailPanel = new Ext.tip.Tip({
        id : 'GlobalTimeLinePanelDetail' ,
        width : gridWidth,                      
    });
}
```

listeners :

```
listeners: {                
                click: function(hdle) {
                    me.showFullDetail(hdle, me);
                },
```

and my function :

```
showFullDetail : function(hdle, me){

        var gTimeLinePanelDetail = Ext.getCmp('GlobalTimeLinePanelDetail');

        if(gTimeLinePanelDetail !=  undefined)
        {   
            var insideChartDetail = me.objChart.cloneConfig();

            // set dimensions
            insideChartDetail.setHeight(30);
            insideChartDetail.setWidth(gridWidth);

            gTimeLinePanelDetail.removeAll();
            gTimeLinePanelDetail.add(insideChartDetail);

            gTimeLinePanelDetail.showAt([xGrid,yMe + me.getHeight()]);
        }       
    },
```

My question is how to change the length of this panel to cover the entire length of the grid knowing that the size of a tooltip is limited to 500px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [default maxWidth](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.tip.ToolTip-cfg-maxWidth) of the tooltip is 500 px. Try changing tooltip's maxWidth config to a greater value. 
For example you could try this in your  code:

```
me.detailPanel = new Ext.tip.Tip({
        id : 'GlobalTimeLinePanelDetail' ,
        width : gridWidth,
        maxWidth : gridWidth                      
    });
```

Comment: Im trying to fix it without changing the css.